# asp:linkbutton after asp:linkbutton not to jump lines

Tags: html, css, asp.net

I have this ASP.NET code:

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" CommandName="Accept" Font-Size="5px">
Accept
   </asp:LinkButton>
<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton2" runat="server" CommandName="Deny" Font-Size="5px">
Deny
   </asp:LinkButton>
```

For some reason the elements are not in the same line.

I can't show it to you in jsFiddle because it doesn't support ASP.NET.

How can I fix it, so it won't jump lines?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this:

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" CommandName="Accept" Font-Size="5px">Accept</asp:LinkButton><asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton2" runat="server" CommandName="Deny" Font-Size="5px">Deny</asp:LinkButton>
```

Keep both the linkbuttons in one line.